# Virtual host on WAMP server works for Firefox only

Tags: browser, wamp, virtualhost

I have installed WAMP Server and added virtual host.

Strange thing:

- On Firefox (my default browser) everything works ok.
- On other browsers (Chrome, IE, Opera) the localhost is ok. I can run
  php files in default directory/subdirectories, phpMyAdmin works ok as
  well.  But **virtual host is not accessible** (error
  DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN or DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG - see comments in hosts file).

**Can you help me to find, why virtual hosts does not work on other browsers than default Firefox?**

I am not experienced in this stuff, so it is possible that I do some very basic mistake.

More details:

- I run WAMP Server 3.2.6 (64 bit) on Windows 10
- I use port 8080 because of some
  port conflict (probably Skype)
- Adding Virtual Host via WAMP was
  "easy", but I have to modify host file (port 8080 was missing).

Windows hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost  
# with    line "127.0.0.1 localhost" browser returns DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
# without line "127.0.0.1 localhost" browser returns DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

127.0.0.1 localhost:8080
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1   sb:8080
::1 sb
```

httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
# Virtual Hosts

NameVirtualHost *.8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName sb
    DocumentRoot "d:/weby/sb/www/"
    <Directory  "d:/weby/sb/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: First upgrade to WAMPServer 3.2.6, the latest version

Comment: Port numbers do not belong in the HOSTS file

Comment: To get to port 8080, you have to place that on the url in the browser address bar. Like `locahost:8080` thats why its normally a bad idea to change the port number

Comment: Suggest you actually work out what is grabbing port 80, could well be IIS so as you are using Apache, you could just uninstall IIS

Comment: @RiggsFolly :  if I delete port numbers in hosts file, then the virtual host does not work at all. On WAMP server homepage I read ERROR: **The ServerName sb:8080 is not defined into hosts file**

Comment: @RiggsFolly : sorry, I really use 3.2.6 version. I have to update the question.

Comment: Did you do - `(right Click) wampmanage->Tools-> Use port other than 80` to tell WAMPServer you wanted to use another port

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yes, i did set `wampmanage->Tools-> Use port other than 80`